# Nginx 502 redirect to other page

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

below is my Nginx conf, I want to redirect my URL to another page if /api throws the error code is 502, How can I do it in nginx.

```
  location ~*/api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3200;
    client_max_body_size 60M;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
  location ~*/api/test {
    rewrite ^/api/test/(.*) /test/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3200;
    client_max_body_size 60M;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
```

I have 2 locations 1) location ~*/api 2/ location ~*/api/test if the location ~*/api gets 502 error i need to redirect to location ~*/api/test

Answer (score 0):

You can use error_page directive.

```
location ~*/api {
    rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3200;
    client_max_body_size 60M;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    error_page 502 @502;
}
```

If you want to write relative path. do like this,

```
location @502 {
    rewrite ^(*)/api(.*) $1/api/test;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3200;
    client_max_body_size 60M;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```

Comment: HI @mariolu,
i have 2 locations 
1) location ~*/api 
2/ location ~*/api/test
if the location ~*/api gets 502 error i need to redirect to location ~*/api/test